# C# Generic Abstract class inherit from Generic Abstract class that pass different generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, abstract

Here's my problem.
I've got generic Singleton class like this :

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : Singleton<T>, new()
{
    private static T instance;
    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance == null ? new T() : instance;
        }
    }
}
```

---

And I wanna create a ProcessManager also is an generic abstract class but with enum generic parameter that inherit from this Singleton class.
This is the code that currently I've made but with error:

```
    public abstract class ProcessManager<TEnum> : Singleton<ProcessManager<TEnum>> where TEnum : Enum, new()
    {
        private TEnum state;
        private Dictionary<TEnum, Action> stateInitializations = new Dictionary<TEnum, Action>();

        public TEnum State
        {
            get { return state; }
            set { InitializeState(state); }
        }

        private void InitializeState(TEnum _state)
        {
            stateInitializations[_state].Invoke();
        }
    }
```

There is a red underline at 'class *ProcessManager*' with error **CS0310**:

> `ProcessManager<TEnum>` must be a non-abstract type with a public
> parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'parameter'
> in the generic type or method `Singleton<T>`

Anyone could tell me how to fix this plz?

Comment: `ProcessManager` cannot be an `abstract` type, the error message literally tells you that.

Comment: I tried to remove 'abstract', it works.. However.. Cause I wanna create GameManager class and GameProcessManager class etc inherit from ProcessManager class, and I don't wanna let it(ProcessManager) be a class that could new itself.. Is this impossible?..

Comment: Make the ProcessManager(s) constructor protected.

Comment: Singleton<T> class require a parameterless constructor but abstract class cannot guarantee its subclasses have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Is that means I need to add a constructor? But what kind of constructor I need to add?

Comment: Your approach doesn't make sense. `public T Instance` needs to be static, or else you would need an instance to access the instance. Once you make it static, then it won't be inherited anyway, so you might as well add the singleton logic to each class that needs it.

Comment: Thanks for the singleton problem, I forgot it. But still I'm confuse how to fix the generic abstract problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `T` is a recursive constraint, you have to force any type that extends `ProcessManager` to map their concrete type onto `T`;

```cs
abstract class ProcessManager<T, E> : Singleton<T>
    where T : ProcessManager<T, E>, new()
    where E : Enum { ... }

class ConcreteType : ProcessManager<ConcreteType, EnumType> { ... }
```

Comment: You are my hero!!! This is what exactly I want! :D  Really appreciate your answer and thank u gratefully!

Answer (score 0):

I tried two way to solve this problem:

1. Remove **ProcessManager**'s *'abstract'*.
2. Remove **Singleton**'s ', *new()*' and also new T.

But second one doesn't make sense,, so I finally decided to use first one..

Anyway really thanks for those nice people who leave comment tried to help me sincerely.